# How to Include an echo function in Include function in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I want to include a file using a PHP include function. But the file name has to be generated dynamically.

For example:

We have URL as domain.com/test
I want to include test-sidebar.php file.

If we have URL as domain.com/test2
I want to include test2-sidebar.php file.

I tried using the following code but unsuccessful.

Please help me, Thanks in Advance.

```
$pageurl = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$editedpageurl = str_replace("/", " ", $pageurl);
$pieces = explode(' ', $editedpageurl);
$last_word = array_pop($pieces);

$sidebar = $last_word."sidebar.php";
include_once('echo $sidebar;');
?>'
```

Comment: just remove the echo and simple quote `include_once($sidebar);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sidebar = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'-sidebar.php';
include_once($sidebar);
```

Answer (score 0):

First and most important thing is single quotes can not understand variables and you are already using php then you do not need to write echo inside the include_once

```
include_once($sidebar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use:

```
include_once($sidebar);
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**, lets make sure that you have had your htaccess (or other rewrite engines) in order to rewrite your ***domain.com/test*** URL to the PHP processing file, and then change these statements to work:

```
# HTACCESS
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
# Change index.php with your file
```

PHP

```
$sidebar = $last_word."-sidebar.php";
include_once($sidebar);
```